# Count within multiple nested lists R

Tags: r

Suppose I have a list of length 2, within which is another list of length 2, within which there is a data frame of numbers coded as either 0, 1 or 2 (bear with me!):

```
set.seed(42)
l1<-data.frame(sample(0:2, 5, replace = TRUE))
l2<-data.frame(sample(0:2, 5, replace = TRUE))
l<-list(l1,l2)
ll<-list(list(l,l), list(l,l))
```

I need to count the number of times either 1 or 2 appears within each data frame. I then need to sum these counts across all counts at the level above.

So for `ll[[1]][[1]][[1]]` the count would be 1, for `ll[[1]][[1]][[2]]` the count would be 4. Across those two dataframes the sum would be 5.

To give a more plain-English description of the real data I'm working with: the top level is the number of species (in this example, 2 species), the level below that is the year when data was recorded (in this example, data is collected in 2 different years). Below that is a location within which data are recorded. I need to know that, within years, how many times 1 or 2 appears across all locations (within that year).

There is perhaps a better way to describe this but so far it's eluding me. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `purrr` functions.

```
library(purrr)
map(ll, function(x) transpose(x) %>% map(~sum(unlist(.x) != 0)))

#[[1]]
#[[1]][[1]]
#[1] 2

#[[1]][[2]]
#[1] 8


#[[2]]
#[[2]][[1]]
#[1] 2

#[[2]][[2]]
#[1] 8
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I think it's pretty much there but I need to keep the numbers grouped into species and year. Your answer returns the correct count but it's a vector of numbers. At present I can't be 100% sure what counts belong to which species and year. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: @Simon You mean `lapply(unlist(ll, recursive = FALSE), function(x) 
  sapply(x, function(y) sum(y != 0)))` ?

Comment: Nearly! This confusion is more due to my terrible explanation than anything else, so thanks for helping and your patience. I think I now need to take the sum of all the first numbers (e.g. sum of `ll[[1]][1]` and `ll[[2]][1]`, and then the sum of `ll[[1]][2]` and `ll[[2]][2]` ... etc. Then I will know, by species, the sum across all locations within a year. The above code tells me the sum within locations, but not also within years.

Comment: It would have helped to verify answers if you could have added expected output to your post.

Comment: Do you need `map(ll, function(x) purrr::transpose(x) %>% map(~sum(unlist(.x) != 0)))` ?

Answer (score 0):

A bit nested, but the solution should work:

```
lapply(ll, 
  function(l) 
    lapply(l, 
      function(li) sum(unlist(li) %in% 1:2)))

# [[1]]
# [[1]][[1]]
# [1] 5
#
# [[1]][[2]]
# [1] 5
# 
# 
# [[2]]
# [[2]][[1]]
# [1] 5
# 
# [[2]][[2]]
# [1] 5
```